# Is there any other word that means “more and more’?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there another word for *more and more*?  For example, in this sentence:

> **More and more** people use computers

Is their a word to replace the *More and more* at the beginning?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with "more and more"? You could for example replace it with *An increasing number of*, but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

> The number of new computer users is a *flooding tide*.

or

> The number of new computer users *waxes* daily.

While both might be thought a tad archaic, a potential advantage is that it forces readers to think about the sentence a fraction longer while absorbing it; thus providing an increased emphasis to the sentence relative to its context.

Answer (score 7):

You could use

> **Increasingly many** people use computers.

Answer (score 0):

> Every day more people use computers.
>
> Every time more people use computers (maybe?)
>
> Use of computers by people (it is obvious by people) is always increasing.
>
> Use of computers is becoming more common every day.